# Replace OR with dynamic sql or IF

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below consider below extract from a query:

```
FROM d_employee e
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[t_etl_employee] t
ON e.customer_nr = t.employee_nr
AND (t.dep_id = @dep_id OR @dep_id IS NULL)
```

Requirement is to replace  `"AND (t.dep_id = @dep_id OR @dep_id IS NULL)"` in above query by dynamic sql or handle with IF statement but in any case OR should be avoided.

---

### Thanks All! I will try to go ahead with COALESCE. Sorry to add a bit more to the question.

```
FROM d_employee e    
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[t_etl_employee] t
     ON e.customer_nr = t.employee_nr
     AND (COALESCE(@dep_id, t.dep_id) =t.dep_id)
     AND ( t.status = 0)
     WHERE e.end_date = N'99991130' 
     AND (t.employee_nr IS NULL
     OR t.employee_shortname <> e.employee_shortname
     OR t.employee_description <> e.employee_description
     OR t.employee_address_1 <> e.t.employee_address_1 
     OR t.nce_code <> e.nce_code
     OR (t.rt_code IS NULL AND e.rt_code IS NOT NULL)
     OR (t.rt_code IS NOT NULL AND e.rt_code IS NULL)
     OR t.is_rated <> e.is_rated
     OR t.is_default <> e.is_default
    )
```

Additional requirement suggested is:
◾splitting the AND and OR statements in the where clause…… then left join could be INNER join for the OR statements (separate statement for left join and IS NULL check)…. not sure how will I split it? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what is the issue with your present query?

Comment: I am trying to achieve performance optimization. Because having an operator and conditional statement would result into a table scan.

Comment: If statement may produce Parameter sniffing problem go with `OR` or `Dynamic Sql`

Comment: I think going with dynamic SQL is the wrong approach. It'd certainly make your query more efficient, but you'd be adding a lot of complexity for a query that is currently very simple.

Comment: We usually can replace `OR` with `UNION` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
...
AND COALESCE(@dep_id, t.dep_id) = t.dep_id
```

Comment: Thanks All! I will try to go ahead with COALESCE. Sorry to add a bit more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your original query - but a dynamic-sql version of it would be this:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @dep_id TINYINT = NULL

SET @cmd = 'SELECT e.customer_nr
FROM d_employee e
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[t_etl_employee] t
ON e.customer_nr = t.employee_nr'
+ IIF(@dep_id IS NOT NULL,' AND t.dep_id = ' + CAST(@dep_id AS NVARCHAR(3)),'')

PRINT @cmd
EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd
```